# ¿Como comprimir varios pdf generados por CrystalReport?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, crystal-reports

A partir de ahora, estoy generando archivos PDF mediante programación utilizando Crystal Report, y quiero que todos esos PDF se compriman pero no encuentro por ningun lado un tutorial o un blog que explique esto.

Hasta el momento voy haciendo esto::

```
//Generar reportes
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Generarreportes(string[] Param)
    {
        //Creo una lista en donde almacenaré los reportes creados
        List<ReportDocument> list_temp = new List<ReportDocument>();

        //Aqui creo los reportes y los añado a la lista
        for (int i = 1; i <= Param.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            DataTable dtInteresado = new DataTable();
            dtInteresado = TablaInteresadoIndividual(obtenerInteresado(Param[0], Param[i]));

            ReportClass Reporte = new ReportClass();
            Reporte.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reportes/"), "ReporteInscritos.rpt"));
            Reporte.SetDataSource(dtInteresado);

            list_temp.Add(Reporte);
        }

        //Y aquí supuestamente deberia estar el código de cómo comprimir todos esos docuemntos, pero desconozco el procedimiento...

        .......

        //Intenté con esto pero me marca error.
        Stream stream = list_temp.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return File(stream, "application/pdf", "ReporteInscritos.pdf"); ;
    }
```

Comment: Quieres comprimir el PDF al mismo tiempo en el que lo descargas ?

Comment: Asi es @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO

Comment: En los tutoriales que he visto, los archivos ya lo tienen listos en una carpeta. En mi caso aún NO EXISTEN hasta que el usuario presione descargar.

Comment: Básicamente el sistema que hago trata de generar certificados dependiendo de las personas que han asistido ha una conferencia. Si han asistido 2 personas, se generaran 2 certificados, etc...

Comment: Pero.. ayer tenias el codigo para comprimir archivos.. si ahora lograste bajarlos a disco, en realidad ya lo solucionaste con lo que tenias ayer...

Comment: Pero no me habías comentado que eso solo sirve para archivos ya generados, o los que tienen ruta local?

Comment: revisa este enlace (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/C-How-to-compress-PDF-f7a27e7c) , tienes que tener en cuenta que primero debes de generar el PDF y después comprimir lo.

Comment: ¿Lograste solucionarlo?